# CPU Usage while running command in command line

Tags: windows, command-line, cpu-usage

I am looking for a way to output CPU usage percentage via the command line. I ran across this: 
`wmic cpu get loadpercentage` which gives me the desired percentage output however I want to test the CPU usage while running a certain command. Anyone have any idea? I tried doing it in a batch file but then realized that at the point i run `wmic cpu get loadpercentage` the CPU usage is no longer portraying the usage of the previous command. Ideally what I am looking for is something like this:

`C:\> command xyz [ftp file.blah]`

and then the file is uploaded correctly but the output is a percentage indicative of the CPU usage during the process. Not sure if I'm making myself clear. Hopefully something like this exists out there. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I misunderstood, but this famous utility from Microsoft's Mark Russinovich does exactly what you have asked

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)

or if you need to do it from the commandline try

[ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900)

Comment: I need to be able to do it from a command line because i need to run the script a few hundred times.

Comment: Hmmmm that seems interesting. Thanks. But from what i've been reading in the documentation it seems like it only works for processes. Maybe i'm missing something. I need it to work with a simple command or a batch file. Any ideas?